# I can't find the format file `luaLaTex.fmt'!

Tags: luatex, mac, lilypond

Working on macOS Monterey. Disclaimer, I'm no expert on LaTex and haven't used it in a while.

Trying to compile a paper using luaLaTex. Has to compile this way to use lyluatex.

Command I'm using:

```
luaLaTex --shell-escape MH_Paper
```

What I'm getting back:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt luaLaTex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /Users/rwr/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /Users/rwr/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: Did not find entry for byfmt=luaLaTex skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 55
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 60
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `luaLaTex.fmt'!
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with lualatex (all in lowercase)

Comment: you seem to have  local config  /Users/rwr/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf specifying a non-standard name?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much! That worked, and I feel so silly now. Thanks again!